# How to return a value based on latest timestamp by group?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two spreadsheets that collect google form data. The first is where a user will make a request, and the second is where an approver will either approve or deny the request. When the first form is filled out, a sequential ID number is assigned. When the supervisor approves or denies the request, the same ID number is recorded in the second spreadsheet.

There could be a 1-to-many relationship between the two spreadsheets, allowing the supervisor to deny a request, and then later approve the same request, or vice-versa.

I need to pull into the first spreadsheet the most recent values from the second spreadsheet, matched on ID number. Based on the images below, for each request id, I need to pull over the values in columns S and U for the latest submission tied to the request ID. Also, since these are tied to google forms, there will be an ever-growing number of rows worth of submissions.

First Spreadsheet - Requests
[image: Requests (First Spreadsheet)]

Second Spreadsheet - Responses (approvals / denials)
[image: Responses (Second Spreadsheet)]

I have been trying to adapt solutions for similar needs that I've found online, but have not found the answer for this particular need.

These are a couple of the solutions I was trying to get to work for me. Column references shown here are from their respective original postings - I no longer have the versions I've modified.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    SORT(
        VLOOKUP(
            QUERY({ROW(B2:B), SORT(A2:B)},"select max(Col1) where Col3 <> '' group by Col3 label max(Col1)''", 0), 
        {ROW(B2:B), SORT(A2:B)},
    {2, 3},
 0), 1, 0)
)


=FILTER( A2:C ; MATCH( A2:A ; QUERY( A2:C ; "select max(A) group by upper(B)" ) ; FALSE ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something simple like:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:E, 1, 0), ROWS(A:A), 2, 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

then for specific column selection just wrap it into query like:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT(A2:E, 1, 0), ROWS(A:A), 2, 2, 1), "select Col5,Col3", 0)
```

[image: 0]